# My kivy program is not working properly, "AssertionError: <Thread(Thread-1 (flood), initial)> is not callable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I started writing a spambot, it's not ready yet, but I noticed that it wasn't running. What's wrong with it? Before I put it the threading it was still working, so obviously there may be a problem there.

```
import time
import pyautogui
import os
import threading 
os.environ["KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG"] = "1"

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set("graphics", "width", "400")
Config.set("graphics", "hight", "100")
Config.set("graphics", "resizable", "0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class asd(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        start_button = Button(text="Start", size=(100, 50), pos=(0, 0))
        start_button.bind(on_press=threading.Thread(target=self.flood))
        start_button.start()
        self.add_widget(start_button)

        text_label = Label(text="Text", size=(100, 50), pos=(100, 300))
        self.add_widget(text_label)

        ammount_label = Label(text="Amount", size=(100, 50), pos=(100, 200))
        self.add_widget(ammount_label)

        delay_label = Label(text="Delay", size=(100, 50), pos=(100, 100))
        self.add_widget(delay_label)



    def flood(self, instance):
        time.sleep(5)
        for i in range(100):
            pyautogui.write("asd")
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            time.sleep(2)


class Spambot(App):
    def build(self):
        return asd()
        
Spambot().run()
```

Comment: This is not a minimal example.  Please write a trivial class which just calls `threading.Thread()`, that will help you find the problem much more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is explicit. Your code:

```
start_button.bind(on_press=threading.Thread(target=self.flood))
```

tries to set a `Thread` object as the callable for the `bind`, but a `Thread` is not callable (i.e.,  you cannot do `Thread_instance()`). One easy fix is to just assign a method as the callable for the `bind`, and in that method create and `start` the `Thread`.